# something error with log4j while building aws athena project

Tags: java, log4j, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

while I building my project with aws athena sdk、 aws java athena sdk、log4j, I failed.
here is the message

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "com.simba.athena.shaded.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
log4j:ERROR The class "com.simba.athena.shaded.apache.log4j.Appender" was 
loaded by 
log4j:ERROR [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] whereas object of type 
log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2].
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "A1".
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Athena</groupId>
<artifactId>Athena</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-athena -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-athena</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.433</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

and my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c -  %m%n
# Turn on DEBUG logging in com.amazonaws.request to log
# a summary of requests/responses with AWS request IDs
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=DEBUG
```

thank you very much

Comment: In which context is your code running that throws this exception? It looks like your application wants to use an Amazon specific logger. Is this error from your application or from an amazon deployed service?

Comment: It's my application. I think it may something error with log4j.properties, beacuse it doesn't throw error if config not contains "amazonaws.request"

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following log4j.properties

```
### Appender
log4j.appender.stdout=com.simba.athena.shaded.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=com.simba.athena.shaded.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
### Log Levels
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
```

Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>athena</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.syncron.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>simba-athena-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
```